# How to modify the size of the x axis text in a twoord plot from the plotrix package?

Tags: r

I would like to make a twoord plot where I would like to decrease the size of the text on the x axis. So I am looking for the alternative to cex.axis. I tried using cexlab.axis but it changes the y axis values.I also tried to suppres the x axis altogether and then customise the x axis by specifying

```
    twoord.plot(lx=1:96, ly=mean_aod, rx=1:96, ry=tot_FCH,type=c("b","bar"),xaxt="n")
    axis(1, at = seq(1, 96, by = 1),srt=45, cex.axis=0.5)
```

But this doesn't get rid of the default labels plotted by twoord.plot. Basically I want the x axis labels to be from 1 to 96 at each of the 96 tick marks. The closest I have got to this is by specifying a variable month that runs from 1 to 96 and then running the code below.

```
   twoord.plot(lx=1:96, ly=mean_aod, rx=1:96, ry=tot_FCH,type=c("b","bar"), xticklab=month)
```

But the size of each label is too big and not all the labels are displayed. How can I rectify this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at `page(twoord.plot)` we see that in `twoord.plot` when `plot` is called, argument `axes` is -already- set to `FALSE` and axes are built by calling `axis`. So, `xaxt` won't have any effect.

The thing is, though, that in the code is written: `axis(1, ... **cex** = axilsab.cex`. But setting `cex` in `axis` won't have the desired effect; `cex.axis` should be used instead. For axes 2 and 4, though, `axilslab.cex` argument is used by calling `mtext`. E.g. `mtext(axat, 2... cex = axislab.cex`; here `cex` (inside `mtext`) has the desired effect.

Concluding, you can write a function `twoord.plot2` where you change the `cex` argument to `cex.axis` when calling `axis(1...`. And then run your code by calling `twoord.plot2`. I.e. `axis(1,... **cex.axis** = axislab.cex)`.

**EDIT**

I will add a `x_axislab.cex` argument in the original `twoord.plot` in order to change **only** the size of x-axis' tickmarks:

Copy-paste everything from `page(twoord.plot)` in a text editor and name it `twoord.plot2`. Then add an extra argument and change the body of the function:

```
twoord.plot2 <- #function (lx, ly, rx, ry, data = NULL, xlim = NULL, lylim = NULL, 
    #rylim = NULL, mar = c(5, 4, 4, 4), lcol = 1, rcol = 2, xlab = "", 
    #ylab = "", rylab = "", lpch = 1, rpch = 2, type = "b", xtickpos = NULL, 
    #xticklab = NULL, halfwidth = 0.4, axislab.cex = 1, 
   **x_axislab.cex = 1**, # do.first = NULL, 
   # ...)  #add argument `x_axislab.cex = 1` in the arguments of the original `twoord.plot`
#{
 #   if (!is.null(data)) {
 #       ly <- unlist(data[ly])

 #...everything else...

 #if (is.null(xticklab)) 
       axis(1, **cex.axis = x_axislab.cex**) #change here. it was **cex = axislab.cex**
  #  else {
 #if (is.null(xtickpos)) 
 #xtickpos <- 1:length(xticklab)
 #  if (is.null(xticklab)) 
  #     xticklab <- xtickpos
    axis(1, at = xtickpos, labels = xticklab, **cex.axis = x_axislab.cex**) #change here. it was **cex = axislab.cex**

 #.....everything else...
```

Then copy-paste your function in `R` and run something like:

```
twoord.plot2(...other arguments..., x_axislab.cex = 0.8)
```

to plot your data and change the size of x-axis' tickmarks.

Comment: Alexis would it be possible for you to supply with some R code for this? I have not yet reached that stage where I am able to write my own R functions. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Alexis, that worked. How can I get a tick mark to be displayed for each value?Currently only the odd numbers are displayed and also how can I get the labels to be loacted nearer to the tick marks?

Comment: @Ridhima: If you have setted `xticklab` to be each and every value you want and it -still- doesn't appear on the plot, then widen the plot so that more tickmarks can appear. (Also, in case you save the plot as `jpeg`, check the `width` and `height` that you'll extract it so that all tickmarks will appear.) To make labels be nearer to the tickmarks you can use the `tcl` argument of the function `axis`. I guess this won't be implemented in `twoord.plot`, so you can add an argument in `twoord.plot2` called `x_tcl = -1` and in the body of `twoord.plot2` use it as `axis(1,..., tcl = x_tcl)`

Comment: Thanks :-) tcl didn't work though, it increases the length of the tick marks but that is not too helpful. I was able to get all the labels though by increasing the plot area. Thanks a tonne